# Single Page Applications - does the JSON payload also carry HTML markup semantics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, single-page-application

Trying to understand SPA's architecture.In SPA the MVC View instead of returning HTML, returns JSON and I understand this for updating *data* based on the JSON response, like having a template iterate over `<li>json-data-here</li>`.

But what happens when the user clicks on a link that should bring up a different page aka different HTML structure? Under SPA will it bring a new page up, like in traditional multipage sites, or will it somehow alter the current page's DOM to present the new structure?.That is if only JSON payload is exchanged, does that also transfer *HTML markup* in order to update the DOM ?

Like in this example, carry both `<li></li>` and the JSON data to be included inside `<li></li>`

Answer (score 1):

Consider each 'page' in a single page application to be a modal pop up that is full screen. Although not immediately obvious, all of the code required to run every page is *always* present - the pages that aren't currently visible are simply hidden from view.

If you have data that is only loaded into page A, then page B will also have full access to that data when page A is not visible, as page A is included in its entirety on page B's DOM.

So essentially yes, the current page's structure is altered to present the new page. It depends on how exactly your JSON is being manipulated, but when the new page is loaded, new markup will indeed be transferred to update the DOM.

Hope this helps! :)